# How can i test that some function is called with object of particular type?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following function - output event

```
hero = {
    id:1,
    name:'Peter',
  }
  clicked() { this.selected.emit(this.hero); }
  @Output() selected = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

**my test code**

```
it('should emit on click', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
    // spy on event emitter
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(component.selected, 'emit');

    // trigger the click
    const nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    component.clicked();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    let hero = {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Peter',
    }

    expect(component.selected.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(hero);
  });
```

here everything works fine - so when i don't emit event the test will fail, but also when the name is not Peter - so when it is John for example the test will fail. This is good for hardcoded values - that needs to be emitted but i will not have harcoded values inside the object that i emit - the id will be different and the name.

How can i test this ?

i wanted totest this - to check if it is called with some particular type for example Hero

```
export interface Hero {
  id:number;
  name: string;
}
```

but i can't find any jasmine matcher for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would get a handle on the arguments that the spy was called with and assert it.

Try something like this:

```
it('should emit on click', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
    // spy on event emitter
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // !! get a handle on emitSpy
    const emitSpy = spyOn(component.selected, 'emit');

    // trigger the click
    const nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    component.clicked();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    let hero = {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Peter',
    }
    // !! get a handle on the most recent argument
    const argument = emitSpy.calls.mostRecent().args[0];
    expect(argument.name).toBeTruthy();
    expect(argument.id).toBeTruthy();
    // !! not sure about this one
    expect(Object.keys(argument).length).toBe(2);
  });
```